# Total no of closed loop paths in 3-by-3 grid

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Rules for making a closed loop path:

1. The path must pass through all points.
2. The path have to pass each point only once.
3. The path is formed by joining only consecutive points (defined below).

The consecutive points are those points that are consecutive horizontally or vertically. But there is one more thing, the left most points are also consecutive to the right most points and the top most points are consecutive to the bottom most points.

Let's take example of 3-by-3 grid:

```
A   B   C

D   E   F

G   H   I
```

$A$ is consecutive to $B$ (if we go right), $C$ (if we go left), $G$ (if we go up) and $D$ (if we go down).

So every point has 4 consecutive points if n > 2, and 
                   2 consecutive points if n = 2,
where n is number of points in each row and each column of a square grid.

An example of the path in the above is $ABCFIHEDGA$

For 2-by-2 case,

```
A   B

C   D
```

there is only one possible path, i.e., $ABDCA$ ($BDCAB$ and $ACDBA$ are same as $ABDCA$, i.e. the order is circular and has no direction).

What is the total no of the paths in 3-by-3 grid? Generalize it for n-by-n grid.

Comment: From G you go down to A.

Comment: Imagine a spherical world :)

Comment: Ahh, I didn't see that part of the descriprion. And the word you're looking for is "torus" or "toroidal", not sphere and spherical.

Comment: The bottom most points are consecutive to top most points... so $A-G$, $B-H$, $C-I$ are consecutive pairs.

Comment: I see it as spherical since all 4 corners are consecutive, top edge is adjacent to the bottom edge and the right edge is adjacent to the left edge.

Comment: No, it's a torus, watch this little animation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0H5_h-RB0T8 That's what you get when you wrap the edges around to meet.

Comment: Wow! thanks for the link. It is toroidal world then. :)

Comment: Is the answer- 22680?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal: I don't know the answer. The question popped up in my mind, after thinking for a while I couldn't solve it, then I posted it here.

Answer (score 2):

There are $48$ such paths for $n=3$. For $n=4$ the count is $1344$ and the relevant sequence does not seem to appear in OEIS.

I counted these by depth-first search.  Here are the $96$ paths you get if you count a path and its reverse as different:

ABCFDEHIG, ABCFEHIGD, ABCFIGHED, ABCFIHEDG, ABCIFDEHG, ABCIFEHGD, ABCIGHEFD, 
   ABCIHEFDG, ABEDFCIHG, ABEDGHIFC, ABEFCIHGD, ABEFDGHIC, ABEHGDFIC, ABEHGICFD, 
   ABEHICFDG, ABEHIGDFC, ABHEDFCIG, ABHEDGIFC, ABHEFCIGD, ABHEFDGIC, ABHGDEFIC, 
   ABHGICFED, ABHICFEDG, ABHIGDEFC, ACBEDFIHG, ACBEFIHGD, ACBEHGIFD, ACBEHIFDG, 
   ACBHEDFIG, ACBHEFIGD, ACBHGIFED, ACBHIFEDG, ACFDEBHIG, ACFDGIHEB, ACFEBHIGD, 
   ACFEDGIHB, ACFIGDEHB, ACFIGHBED, ACFIHBEDG, ACFIHGDEB, ACIFDEBHG, ACIFDGHEB, 
   ACIFEBHGD, ACIFEDGHB, ACIGDFEHB, ACIGHBEFD, ACIHBEFDG, ACIHGDFEB, ADEBCFIHG, 
   ADEBHGIFC, ADEFCBHIG, ADEFCIGHB, ADEFICBHG, ADEFIGHBC, ADEHBCFIG, ADEHGIFCB, 
   ADFCBEHIG, ADFCIGHEB, ADFEBCIHG, ADFEBHGIC, ADFEHBCIG, ADFEHGICB, ADFICBEHG, 
   ADFIGHEBC, ADGHBEFIC, ADGHEFICB, ADGHICFEB, ADGHIFEBC, ADGICFEHB, ADGIFEHBC, 
   ADGIHBEFC, ADGIHEFCB, AGDEBHIFC, AGDEFCIHB, AGDEFIHBC, AGDEHIFCB, AGDFCIHEB, 
   AGDFEBHIC, AGDFEHICB, AGDFIHEBC, AGHBCIFED, AGHBEDFIC, AGHEBCIFD, AGHEDFICB, 
   AGHICBEFD, AGHICFDEB, AGHIFCBED, AGHIFDEBC, AGICBHEFD, AGICFDEHB, AGIFCBHED, 
   AGIFDEHBC, AGIHBCFED, AGIHBEDFC, AGIHEBCFD, AGIHEDFCB

Mathematica code:

```
n = 3;
pts = Tuples[Range[0, n - 1], 2];
adj[x_, y_] := 
adj[x, y] = (Count[x - y, 0] == 1) && MemberQ[{1, n - 1}, Max[Abs[x - y]]];
extensions[p_] := Select[Complement[pts, p], adj[Last[p], #] &];

DFS[p_] := (
   If[Length[p] == n^2 && adj[First[p], Last[p]], Sow[p]; Return];
   Scan[DFS[Append[p, #]] &, extensions[p]]);
paths = Reap[DFS[{{0, 0}}]][[2, 1]];
```

Comment: Sorry I don't have knowledge of coding in Mathematica. Can you please give a mathematical solution if possible?

Comment: It's extremely unlikely that there's a mathematical formula for the number of Hamiltonian cycles in the toroidal grid graph. The counting problem in general lies at the intersection of mathematics and computer science; the trick is to come up with an enumeration strategy which doesn't require constructing every cycle.  Looking up "Hamiltonian cycles" at OEIS.org, I ran across a recent research paper that might help you: http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v21i4p7

Comment: Thanks for the link. Have to learn about Hamiltonian cycles. BTW I am thinking of approaching the problem by using concepts of dominoes and fundamental counting principle like this: For 3*3 grid, we have 18 dominoes out of which 9 of them have to be connected to form a closed path. But I don't know if I am getting answer correctly (I get 6*3*3*2*2 = 216).

Comment: The "fundamental counting principle" I believe you are referring to only applies when the number of choices available at each step is independent of the choices made at previous steps.  That's not the case here.  I'm quite certain I gave you the correct answer.